# Converting numpy ndarray with dtype <U30 into float

Tags: python, arrays, string, pandas, numpy

I'm reading a list from pandas dataframe cell.

```
>>from pandas import DataFrame as table
>>x = table.loc[table['person'] == int(123), table.columns != 'xyz']['segment'][0]
>>print("X = ",x)
```

where 'person' and 'segment' are my column names and segment contains a list with floating values.

```
>>X = [[39.414, 39.498000000000005]]
```

Now, when I try to convert this into a numpy array,

```
>>x = numpy.asarray(x)
>>x=x.astype(float)
```

I get the following error

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[[39.414, 39.498000000000005]]'
```

I have tried parsing the string and tried to remove any "\n" or " " or any unnecessary quotes, but it does not work. Then I tried to find the dtype

```
>>print("Dtype = ", x.dtype)
>>Dtype = <U30
```

I assume that we need to convert the U30 dtype into floats, but I am not sure how to do it. I am using numpy version 1.15.0.

All I want to do is, to parse the  above list into a list with floating point values.

Comment: can you add some mock data so this is reproducible?

Comment: Looks like you have a string representation of a list.  Try using `ast.literal_eval(x)` first.  Do it on the entire column to make this easier: `df.segment = df.segment.apply(ast.literal_eval)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The datatype should have tipped you off.  `U30` here stands for a length 30 unicode string (Which is what you'll see if you type `len(x)`.

What you have is the string representation of a list, not a list of strings/floats/etc..

You need to use the `ast` library here:

```
x = '[[39.414, 39.498000000000005]]'
x = ast.literal_eval(x)
np.array(x, dtype=float)
```

```
array([[39.414, 39.498]])
```

Answer (score 2):

For the specific format you see, consider [`np.fromstring`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html). With string slicing you can also remove the unused dimension:

```
x = '[[39.414, 39.498000000000005]]'

res = np.fromstring(x[2:-2], sep=',')

# array([ 39.414,  39.498])
```

Comment: Hi! This works for the above example, but does not work for muti dimensional arrays like this : x = '[[39.414, 39.498000000000005],[344.234234,442.23432]]'. In that case x = ast.literal_eval(x) followed by
np.array(x, dtype=float) is more suitable

Comment: @appsdownload, Yes, hence the comment `For the specific format you see`.

Comment: Oh. Thank you @jpp. Also can you help me understand which one would be more efficient if I have a specific format?

Comment: I'm not sure. That's a separate question, but look up the `timeit` module and you can test for yourself!